# toggle element on click

Tags: javascript, html

```js
/**
 * Plugin: RichTile
 *
 * Because I got a little ambitious and decided to include ARIA attributes
 * and stuff, it became easier to manage this as a plugin.
 */

var RichTile = function (element, options) {
  this.element = $(element);
  this.options = $.extend({}, RichTile.DEFAULTS, options);
  this.flyoutElement = this.element.find(this.options.flyout);
  this.toggleElement = this.element.find(this.options.toggle);
  
  this.toggleElement.on({
    'click.RichTile': $.proxy(this.clickHandler, this),
    'keyup.RichTile': $.proxy(this.keyHandler, this)
  });
};

RichTile.DATA_KEY = 'plugin_richTile';

RichTile.DEFAULTS = {
  flyout: '.js-tile-flyout',
  toggle: '.js-toggle-tile',
  expandedClass: 'is-expanded',
  disabledClass: 'is-disabled',
  toggleKeyCodes: [13, 32] // ENTER, SPACE
};

RichTile.prototype.isExpanded = function() {
  return this.element.hasClass(this.options.expandedClass);
};

RichTile.prototype.isDisabled = function() {
  return this.element.hasClass(this.options.disabledClass);
};

RichTile.prototype.isEnabled = function() {
  return ! this.isDisabled();
};

RichTile.prototype.toggle = function(expand) {
  if (typeof expand === 'undefined') {
    expand = ! this.isExpanded();
  }
  if (this.isEnabled() || !expand) {
    this.flyoutElement.attr('aria-hidden', ! expand);
    this.toggleElement.attr('aria-expanded', expand);
    this.element.toggleClass(this.options.expandedClass, expand);
    this.element.trigger((expand ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed') + '.RichTile', [ this ]);
  }
  return this;
};

RichTile.prototype.expand = function() {
  return this.toggle(true);
};

RichTile.prototype.collapse = function() {
  return this.toggle(false);
};

RichTile.prototype.toggleEnable = function(enable) {
  if (typeof enable === 'undefined') {
    enable = this.isDisabled();
  }
  this.toggleElement.filter('[tabindex]').attr({
    'tabindex': enable ? 0 : -1,
    'aria-disabled': ! enable
  });
  if (! enable) {
    this.toggle(false);
  }
  this.element.toggleClass(this.options.disabledClass, ! enable);
  this.element.trigger((enable ? 'enabled' : 'disabled') + '.RichTile', [ this ]);
  return this;
};

RichTile.prototype.enable = function() {
  return this.toggleEnable(true);
};

RichTile.prototype.disable = function() {
  return this.toggleEnable(false);
};

RichTile.prototype.clickHandler = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return this.toggle();
};

RichTile.prototype.keyHandler = function(event) {
  if (this.options.toggleKeyCodes.indexOf(event.which) > -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return this.toggle();
  }
};

$.fn.richTile = function(option) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var data = $.data(this, RichTile.DATA_KEY);

    if (!data) {
      $.data(this, RichTile.DATA_KEY, (data = new RichTile(this, typeof option === 'object' && option)));
    }
    
    if (typeof option === 'string') {
      data[option]();
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Apply plugin and account for desired behavior outside of individual toggles.
 */

$('.js-tile').richTile().on({
  'expanded.RichTile': function(event, tile) {
    // disable siblings on expand
    var siblings = tile.element.siblings('.js-tile');
    siblings.richTile('disable');
    // re-enable when this tile is collapsed
    tile.element.one('collapsed.RichTile', function() {
      siblings.richTile('enable');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
/**
 * Variables
 */
/**
 * Scaffolding
 */
* {
  margin: 0;
}

* + * {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

html {
  background: #444;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  color: #e1e1e1;
  font: 1em/1.5 "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 1rem;
  max-width: 64em;
}

h1,
a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

pre,
code {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
}

/**
 * Component: Grid
 *
 * https://github.com/suitcss/components-grid/
 */
.Grid {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.Grid--withGutter {
  margin: 0 -0.5rem;
}

.Grid--withGutter > .Grid-cell {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.Grid-cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Component: Card
 */
.Card-image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.Card-image:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.Card-image img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Card-expiry {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 0.6666666667em;
}

/**
 * Component: Input
 */
.Input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.Input:hover {
  border-color: #aaa;
}
.Input:focus {
  border-color: #08c;
  outline: 0;
}
.Input.is-visa, .Input.is-mastercard, .Input.is-amex {
  background-position: 0.75rem center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 3.375rem;
}
.Input.is-visa {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-visa.svg");
}
.Input.is-mastercard {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-mastercard.svg");
}
.Input.is-amex {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-amex.svg");
}

/**
 * Component: Button
 */
.Button {
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  color: #08c;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
.Button:focus, .Button:hover {
  color: #00aaff;
}

.Button--primary {
  background: #08c;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.Button--primary:focus, .Button--primary:hover {
  background: #00aaff;
}

/**
 * Component: Tiles
 */
.Tiles {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.Tile {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.Tile-content {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  color: #444;
  margin: 1rem 0.5rem 0;
  min-height: 10em;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.Tile-content--toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Tile-content--toggle:focus, .Tile-content--toggle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #75d1ff;
  outline: 0;
}

.Tile.is-disabled .Tile-content--toggle {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.Tile.is-disabled .Tile-content--toggle:focus, .Tile.is-disabled .Tile-content--toggle:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.Tile-flyout {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.Tile.is-expanded .Tile-flyout {
  display: block;
}

.Tile-flyout:before {
  background: #fff;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1rem;
  top: -0.5rem;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 1rem;
}

/**
 * Breakpoint layout changes
 */
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .Tile {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .Tile-flyout {
    width: 200%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(2n+1) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(2n+1) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 25%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(2n+2) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(2n+2) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 75%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .Tile {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
  }

  .Tile-flyout {
    width: 300%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(3n+1) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(3n+1) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 16.6666666667%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(3n+2) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(3n+2) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 50%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(3n+3) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(3n+3) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 83.3333333333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .Tile {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .Tile-flyout {
    width: 400%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(4n+1) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(4n+1) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 12.5%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(4n+2) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(4n+2) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 37.5%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(4n+3) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(4n+3) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 62.5%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(4n+4) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(4n+4) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 87.5%;
  }
}
/**
 * Utilities: Space
 */
.u-marginTop {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .u-md-no-marginTop {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
/**
 * Utilities: Size
 *
 * https://github.com/suitcss/utils-size/
 */
.u-size1of2 {
  width: 50% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .u-md-size1of2 {
    width: 50% !important;
  }
}
/**
 * Utilities: Text
 * 
 * https://github.com/suitcss/utils-text/
 */
.u-textCenter {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.u-textRight {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Responsive tiles with column-spanning flyouts</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600|Source+Code+Pro'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="Tiles">
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-0">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-visa.svg" alt="Visa">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; 1234</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires May 2017</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-0" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-visa" type="text" value="XXXX XXXX XXXX 1234">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="05 / 17" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-1">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-mastercard.svg" alt="Mastercard">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; 0000</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires July 2018</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-1" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-mastercard" type="text" value="XXXX XXXX XXXX 0000">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="07 / 18" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-2">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-amex.svg" alt="American Express">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;1001</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires February 2019</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-2" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-amex" type="text" value="XXXX XXXXXX X1001">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="02 / 19" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-3">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-visa.svg" alt="Visa">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; 1234</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires May 2017</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-3" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-visa" type="text" value="XXXX XXXX XXXX 1234">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="05 / 17" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-4">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-mastercard.svg" alt="Mastercard">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; 0000</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires July 2018</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-4" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-mastercard" type="text" value="XXXX XXXX XXXX 0000">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="07 / 18" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-5">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-amex.svg" alt="American Express">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;1001</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires February 2019</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-5" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-amex" type="text" value="XXXX XXXXXX X1001">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="02 / 19" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am really new with html / javascript.

I am playing around with this code i found in google.

I wanted to know how would i make the flyout hide when i click anywhere on the window part from the flyout itself.

Currently to hide the flyout you have to click back on the main picture, or click a button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to determine if a click made anywhere in the document has been done inside a `.Tile-flyout` or inside a `.js-tile` that is not "disabled".

```
// A click outside something active
$(document).on("click", function(e){
  // the click did not occur inside a tile "flyout" or inside an "not disabled" tile
  if(!($(e.target).closest(".Tile-flyout").length == 1 || $(e.target).closest(".js-tile:not(.is-disabled)").length == 1)){
    console.log("CLOSE!")
    
    // Then simply simulate a click in the active one
    $(".is-expanded>div").trigger("click")
  }
})
```

```js
/**
 * Plugin: RichTile
 *
 * Because I got a little ambitious and decided to include ARIA attributes
 * and stuff, it became easier to manage this as a plugin.
 */

var RichTile = function (element, options) {
  this.element = $(element);
  this.options = $.extend({}, RichTile.DEFAULTS, options);
  this.flyoutElement = this.element.find(this.options.flyout);
  this.toggleElement = this.element.find(this.options.toggle);
  
  this.toggleElement.on({
    'click.RichTile': $.proxy(this.clickHandler, this),
    'keyup.RichTile': $.proxy(this.keyHandler, this)
  });
};

RichTile.DATA_KEY = 'plugin_richTile';

RichTile.DEFAULTS = {
  flyout: '.js-tile-flyout',
  toggle: '.js-toggle-tile',
  expandedClass: 'is-expanded',
  disabledClass: 'is-disabled',
  toggleKeyCodes: [13, 32] // ENTER, SPACE
};

RichTile.prototype.isExpanded = function() {
  return this.element.hasClass(this.options.expandedClass);
};

RichTile.prototype.isDisabled = function() {
  return this.element.hasClass(this.options.disabledClass);
};

RichTile.prototype.isEnabled = function() {
  return ! this.isDisabled();
};

RichTile.prototype.toggle = function(expand) {
  if (typeof expand === 'undefined') {
    expand = ! this.isExpanded();
  }
  if (this.isEnabled() || !expand) {
    this.flyoutElement.attr('aria-hidden', ! expand);
    this.toggleElement.attr('aria-expanded', expand);
    this.element.toggleClass(this.options.expandedClass, expand);
    this.element.trigger((expand ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed') + '.RichTile', [ this ]);
  }
  return this;
};

RichTile.prototype.expand = function() {
  return this.toggle(true);
};

RichTile.prototype.collapse = function() {
  return this.toggle(false);
};

RichTile.prototype.toggleEnable = function(enable) {
  if (typeof enable === 'undefined') {
    enable = this.isDisabled();
  }
  this.toggleElement.filter('[tabindex]').attr({
    'tabindex': enable ? 0 : -1,
    'aria-disabled': ! enable
  });
  if (! enable) {
    this.toggle(false);
  }
  this.element.toggleClass(this.options.disabledClass, ! enable);
  this.element.trigger((enable ? 'enabled' : 'disabled') + '.RichTile', [ this ]);
  return this;
};

RichTile.prototype.enable = function() {
  return this.toggleEnable(true);
};

RichTile.prototype.disable = function() {
  return this.toggleEnable(false);
};

RichTile.prototype.clickHandler = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return this.toggle();
};

RichTile.prototype.keyHandler = function(event) {
  if (this.options.toggleKeyCodes.indexOf(event.which) > -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return this.toggle();
  }
};

$.fn.richTile = function(option) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var data = $.data(this, RichTile.DATA_KEY);

    if (!data) {
      $.data(this, RichTile.DATA_KEY, (data = new RichTile(this, typeof option === 'object' && option)));
    }
    
    if (typeof option === 'string') {
      data[option]();
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Apply plugin and account for desired behavior outside of individual toggles.
 */

$('.js-tile').richTile().on({
  'expanded.RichTile': function(event, tile) {
    // disable siblings on expand
    var siblings = tile.element.siblings('.js-tile');
    siblings.richTile('disable');
    // re-enable when this tile is collapsed
    tile.element.one('collapsed.RichTile', function() {
      siblings.richTile('enable');
    });
  }
});

// A click outside something active
$(document).on("click", function(e){
  // the click did not occur inside a tile "flyout" or inside an "not disabled" tile
  if(!($(e.target).closest(".Tile-flyout").length == 1 || $(e.target).closest(".js-tile:not(.is-disabled)").length == 1)){
    console.log("CLOSE!")
    
    // Then simply simulate a click in the active one
    $(".is-expanded>div").trigger("click")
  }
})
```

```css
/**
 * Variables
 */
/**
 * Scaffolding
 */
* {
  margin: 0;
}

* + * {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

html {
  background: #444;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  color: #e1e1e1;
  font: 1em/1.5 "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 1rem;
  max-width: 64em;
}

h1,
a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

pre,
code {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
}

/**
 * Component: Grid
 *
 * https://github.com/suitcss/components-grid/
 */
.Grid {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.Grid--withGutter {
  margin: 0 -0.5rem;
}

.Grid--withGutter > .Grid-cell {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.Grid-cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Component: Card
 */
.Card-image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.Card-image:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.Card-image img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Card-expiry {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 0.6666666667em;
}

/**
 * Component: Input
 */
.Input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.Input:hover {
  border-color: #aaa;
}
.Input:focus {
  border-color: #08c;
  outline: 0;
}
.Input.is-visa, .Input.is-mastercard, .Input.is-amex {
  background-position: 0.75rem center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 3.375rem;
}
.Input.is-visa {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-visa.svg");
}
.Input.is-mastercard {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-mastercard.svg");
}
.Input.is-amex {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-amex.svg");
}

/**
 * Component: Button
 */
.Button {
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  color: #08c;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
.Button:focus, .Button:hover {
  color: #00aaff;
}

.Button--primary {
  background: #08c;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.Button--primary:focus, .Button--primary:hover {
  background: #00aaff;
}

/**
 * Component: Tiles
 */
.Tiles {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.Tile {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.Tile-content {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  color: #444;
  margin: 1rem 0.5rem 0;
  min-height: 10em;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.Tile-content--toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Tile-content--toggle:focus, .Tile-content--toggle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #75d1ff;
  outline: 0;
}

.Tile.is-disabled .Tile-content--toggle {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.Tile.is-disabled .Tile-content--toggle:focus, .Tile.is-disabled .Tile-content--toggle:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.Tile-flyout {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.Tile.is-expanded .Tile-flyout {
  display: block;
}

.Tile-flyout:before {
  background: #fff;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1rem;
  top: -0.5rem;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 1rem;
}

/**
 * Breakpoint layout changes
 */
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .Tile {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .Tile-flyout {
    width: 200%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(2n+1) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(2n+1) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 25%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(2n+2) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(2n+2) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 75%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .Tile {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
  }

  .Tile-flyout {
    width: 300%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(3n+1) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(3n+1) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 16.6666666667%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(3n+2) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(3n+2) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 50%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(3n+3) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(3n+3) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 83.3333333333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .Tile {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .Tile-flyout {
    width: 400%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(4n+1) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(4n+1) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 12.5%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(4n+2) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(4n+2) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 37.5%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(4n+3) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(4n+3) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 62.5%;
  }

  .Tile:nth-child(4n+4) .Tile-flyout {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  .Tile:nth-child(4n+4) .Tile-flyout:before {
    left: 87.5%;
  }
}
/**
 * Utilities: Space
 */
.u-marginTop {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .u-md-no-marginTop {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
/**
 * Utilities: Size
 *
 * https://github.com/suitcss/utils-size/
 */
.u-size1of2 {
  width: 50% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .u-md-size1of2 {
    width: 50% !important;
  }
}
/**
 * Utilities: Text
 * 
 * https://github.com/suitcss/utils-text/
 */
.u-textCenter {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.u-textRight {
  text-align: right !important;
}

/* ADDED to restore the SO console's style */
.as-console{
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Responsive tiles with column-spanning flyouts</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600|Source+Code+Pro'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="Tiles">
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-0">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-visa.svg" alt="Visa">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; 1234</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires May 2017</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-0" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-visa" type="text" value="XXXX XXXX XXXX 1234">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="05 / 17" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-1">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-mastercard.svg" alt="Mastercard">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; 0000</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires July 2018</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-1" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-mastercard" type="text" value="XXXX XXXX XXXX 0000">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="07 / 18" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-2">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-amex.svg" alt="American Express">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;1001</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires February 2019</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-2" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-amex" type="text" value="XXXX XXXXXX X1001">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="02 / 19" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-3">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-visa.svg" alt="Visa">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; 1234</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires May 2017</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-3" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-visa" type="text" value="XXXX XXXX XXXX 1234">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="05 / 17" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-4">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-mastercard.svg" alt="Mastercard">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; 0000</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires July 2018</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-4" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-mastercard" type="text" value="XXXX XXXX XXXX 0000">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="07 / 18" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Tile js-tile">
    <div class="Tile-content Tile-content--toggle js-toggle-tile"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="edit-flyout-5">
      <div class="Card-image">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62127/creditcard-amex.svg" alt="American Express">
      </div>
      <pre class="Card-code"><code>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; &#9679;1001</code></pre>
      <p class="Card-expiry">Expires February 2019</p>
    </div>
    <form class="Tile-flyout js-tile-flyout"
      id="edit-flyout-5" 
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="Tile-content">
        <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter">
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2">
            <label>
              Card Number
              <input class="Input is-amex" type="text" value="XXXX XXXXXX X1001">
            </label>
            <label>
              Full Name on Card
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="John Smith">
            </label>
            <div class="Grid Grid--withGutter u-marginTop">
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Expiration Date
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="02 / 19" placeholder="MM / YY">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="Grid-cell u-size1of2">
                <label>
                  Security Code
                  <input class="Input" type="text" value="XXX">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Grid-cell u-md-size1of2 u-marginTop u-md-no-marginTop">
            <label>
              Address Line 1
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="208 SW 1st Ave">
            </label>
            <label>
              Address Line 2
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="Ste. 240">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zip/Postal Code
              <input class="Input" type="text" value="97204">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-textRight">
          <button class="Button js-toggle-tile" type="button">Never Mind</button>
          <button class="Button Button--primary js-toggle-tile" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, how would i make it so that if i dont click save it restores the values to default?

Comment: The question was about clicking outside an active thing.... For the rest, it is up to you.